# Wrapping C code with ctypes and using Scipy in python to do optimization with it

Tags: python, c, scipy, typeerror, ctypes

I have successfully wrapped some C code using ctypes and brought into Python. I am trying to use Scipy to do optimization on it using the direct method and I am getting this error: TypeError: this function takes at least 2 arguments (1 given).
Below is my code and the print statments and errors that I am getting:

in file ctype_tutorial.py:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np
from numpy import ctypeslib
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import direct, Bounds, basinhopping

clibrary = ctypes.CDLL(r"C:\Users\mhaja\OneDrive\Desktop\Github\Honours\ctypes\clibrary.so")

styblinski_tang = clibrary.styblinski_tang

styblinski_tang.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int]
styblinski_tang.restype = ctypes.c_int


print(styblinski_tang(1, 1))

result = direct(styblinski_tang, [[-4,4], [-4,4]])
print(result.x, result.fun, result.nfev)
```

in clibrary.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int styblinski_tang(int x, int y){
    return 0.5 * (pow(x, 4) - 16*pow(x, 2) + 5*x + pow(y, 4) - 16*pow(y, 2) + 5*y);
}
```

Error that I am getting:

```
-10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\mhaja\OneDrive\Desktop\Github\Honours\ctypes\ctypes_tutorial.py", line 44, in <module>
    result = direct(styblinski_tang, [[-4,4], [-4,4]])
  File "C:\Users\mhaja\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_direct_py.py", line 256, in direct
    x, fun, ret_code, nfev, nit = _direct(
  File "C:\Users\mhaja\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_direct_py.py", line 249, in _func_wrap
    f = func(x)
TypeError: this function takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I can see that I am successfully wrapping the function cause when I try the input of 1,1 on the function I get the correct output of -10 but when I try to use Scipy on it, i get the error. I think it might be due to the ctypes and how it converts between C and python. Any help will be appreciated with either Ctypes or Scipy. I am doing this for my honours so please help.

update: It was suggested to me to add a wrapper method so I did and this is the updated code:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np
from numpy import ctypeslib
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import direct, Bounds, basinhopping

clibrary = ctypes.CDLL(r"C:\Users\mhaja\OneDrive\Desktop\Github\Honours\ctypes\clibrary.so")

styblinski_tang = clibrary.styblinski_tang

styblinski_tang.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int]
styblinski_tang.restype = ctypes.c_int


print(styblinski_tang(1, 1))

# Using a wrapper function 
def foo(xy):
    x,y = xy
    return styblinski_tang(x, y)

print(foo([1,1]))

result = direct(foo, [[-4,4], [-4,4]])
print(result.x, result.fun, result.nfev)
```

This helped a bit but I am still getting this error message:

```
-10
-10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\mhaja\OneDrive\Desktop\Github\Honours\ctypes\ctypes_tutorial.py", line 51, in <module>
    result = direct(foo, [[-4,4], [-4,4]])
  File "C:\Users\mhaja\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_direct_py.py", line 256, in direct
    x, fun, ret_code, nfev, nit = _direct(
  File "C:\Users\mhaja\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_direct_py.py", line 249, in _func_wrap
    f = func(x)
  File "c:\Users\mhaja\OneDrive\Desktop\Github\Honours\ctypes\ctypes_tutorial.py", line 47, in foo
    return styblinski_tang(x, y)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: TypeError: wrong type
```

Comment: Your ``fun(1,1)` is passing 2 arguments to the function. `direct(fun, bounds..)` passes 1 argument, a 1d array with shape (n,) (see the docs).  You aren't using `args` to pass any other arguments.  I'm guessing `n` comes from the `bounds`, which appears to be a (2,2).

Comment: working from the code image is less than ideal, though somewhat workable.

Comment: Can you put the code into the question, rather than a screenshot?

Comment: Add full code and exception trace  **as text in the question not as image**. [\[SO\]: Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
**[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**
for more asking related details.

Comment: @hpaulj hello thank you for help I have added the source code please take another look at it.

Comment: See how `direct` is calling `func(x)`, but your function expects `styblinski_tang(x, y)`

Comment: @hpaulj so how do I correct it? Do I have to make sure that my function always only takes in one parameter or does that parameter have to be an array containing two elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a wrapper function

```
def foo(xy):
   x,y = xy
   # or x=xy[0]; y=xy[1]
   return styblinski_tang(x, y)
```

Comment: After using the wrapper I got this error: "ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: TypeError: wrong type"

Comment: You may need to explicitly convert the `x` and `y` to `int`.  They may be `np.int32` objects, and your `c` derived code is picky about the difference.

Comment: After adding float() to the x and y it worked. Thank you so much man @hpaulj, you a real one build like ronaldo but for coding.

Answer (score -1):

your conversion is wrong and that is why you are running into a problem there is nothing wrong with the scipy part but its the ctypes part that its messing it up. Look up how to import the CDLL on youtube and you will get your answer.

Comment: Hello thaank you for your response but I am pretty sure that the ctypes is right since when I give the input of 1,1 I get the output of 10 which is correct. I think that the Ctypes and scipy are having problems working together and that is where my problem is but would love feedback on it.